# segmentation fault when connecting to mysql database with c

Tags: mysql, c, unix, segmentation-fault

Does anyone know why the following would cause a segmentation fault when run?

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
    printf("MySQL client version : %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
    MYSQL *conn=NULL;
    mysql_init(conn);
    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "root";
    char *password = "pass";
    char *database = "weather";
    char *table ="room_temp";
    char *tst_qry="INSERT INTO `weather`.`room_temp` (`idx`, `date`, `temperature`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '10')";

        mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0);


}
```

I complied as follows

```
gcc -o mysql $(mysql_config --cflags) mysql.c $(mysql_config --libs)
```

The output was as follows,

```
MySQL client version : 5.5.31
Segmentation fault
```

Please help!

Comment: You're passing a null pointer as the first argument to `mysql_real_connect`.

Comment: I think thats right. Do this instead `MYSQL conn;mysql_init(&conn);mysql_real_connect(&conn, server, user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a `NULL`-pointer to `mysql_real_connect`. According to the documentation `mysql_init` returns an initialized `MYSQL` object (when passed a `NULL`-pointer). Change your code either to this to use the return value:

```
conn = mysql_init(conn);
```

or this, to have `mysql_init` fill the object:

```
MYSQL conn; /* note that this isn't a pointer */
mysql_init(&conn);
...
mysql_real_connect(&conn, ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

The allocated *new* object isn't stored in your code. Hence you are passing the NULL to  `mysql_real_connect()`.

Change this line:

```
mysql_init(conn);
```

to:

```
conn = mysql_init(conn);
```

or rather directly:

```
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```